# Hidden text boxes show on exporting SSRS report to Excel

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel, show-hide

I have a report with two groups that are expandable and collapsible.  On opening the report the group header shows with totals but on clicking the toggle button the report expands out and the outgroup totals are set to visible = false.  This all works fine until I export to excel.  The data in the text boxes show no matter what I try.  I have tried using  =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name= "EXCELOPENXML" OR Globals!RenderFormat.Name= "EXCEL", true, false) in the expression but the data still shows.  I've tried setting the DataElementOutput to NoOutput but it still shows.  The only thing that seems to work is if the initial state of the text box is set to visible = false but I need this to be set to true.  Anyone know of any way of doing this?